# URL of a Facebook live stream for sharing

Tags: facebook, video-streaming

When I try to plan a live stream on Facebook on my personal profile, after creating a post about the scheduled live stream, the live stream URL which I can share never appears (server's URL and streaming key do appear, but the live stream URL doesn't appear).

How can I fix this?

I need live stream's URL in order to be able to connect the planned Zoom meeting with the planned Facebook live stream.